# Need to find record, but only know ID, not table

Tags: postgresql

I want to find a record in my PostgreSQL database with a certain UUID. Unfortunately I don't know its table name, only its UUID.

How can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

From a `psql` session, use a `DO` block like this, and it will print out tables where your `uuid` is found:

```
do $$
declare
  sdata record;
  _count bigint;
begin
  for sdata in select table_schema as tschema, table_name as tname, column_name as cname
                 from information_schema.columns
                where data_type = 'uuid'
  loop
    execute format('select count(*) from %I.%I where %I = %L',
                   sdata.tschema, sdata.tname, sdata.cname, 
                   <your uuid here>)
       into _count;
      if _count > 0 then
        raise notice '%.% % %', sdata.tschema, sdata.tname, sdata.cname, _count;
      end if;
  end loop;
end
$$;
```